# Edit a string in all tables of an msi database c#

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, windows-installer

Is there any way to edit all tables of an msi database installer.For example i have a string 
"label" in some of the coulmn of certain tables in installer.I want to replace the "label" with "text".I Am using the Api Windowsinstaller in c#

```
using Windowsinstaller
```

thanks

Comment: Is this something that has to be done programmatically, or do you just need to edit the msi?

Comment: This has to be done programmatically.

Comment: Please provide more information about what it is that you are trying to accomplish. Localization? Changing a property value? Transform a database? Redirection?

Comment: Hi Mark Rovetta,
Currenty i have a package and it contain files of latest version of dlls and infs.I have to replace this dlls and infs with some locked version of dlls and infs.This locked version have different name than that of the current version.So i have to edit the corresponing entries in msi installer as well.I couldn't use installshield or Orca.I have to do this thing programmatically.i can use python or c# Please help. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'locked versions.'  If you need to replace files with files having a different name, then that requires installing a component with a new component code.